# Does a Helix shaped object floating in water stream rotate?

Tags: torque, buoyancy

A Helix shaped light weight object is placed a water stream.   Does it rotate? 
It is pushed by water body,  will it also experience turning force and thus rotate?

Comment: Such an object is called a [turbine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbine). Searching for "helical turbine" brings up some interesting results.

Comment: Turbines are held firmly (but free to rotate)  on a shift and force of air or water will produce a torque. But my question referred to an object which floats freely in moving water.

Answer (score 1):

If the water is moving uniformly and we ignore air resistance, then for any object (not just a helix), there are no forces from the water that can provide ongoing torques to spin it.  If the object is symmetric, it will have no net torque from the water to accelerate it.  If the object is asymmetric, it will rotate until it lies in the lowest energy orientation and then stay there.

Continuous spinning of an object in water requires a continuous input of energy and there is no available energy in a uniform body of water.

In the real world, there are two places where such energy could come from: the water may not be completely uniform (may have fast and slow flow areas), and the difference in the water velocity and the air velocity can be exploited (sailing).

Comment: Thanks BowlOfRed. I agree to your point that there are no net forces from moving mass of water that can spin.  This discussion was about this video https://youtu.be/xIg0ADyA7u0. My point is that if it is not firmly gripped axially like a turbine it cannot rotate.  it is argued that linear resistance of the piece causing difference in velocity offers such support to facilitate rotation. Is that possible (assuming there are no lateral forces)?

Comment: A very late response, but this isn't true. Enjoy the video: https://youtube.com/shorts/-_LmcIaPMAQ?feature=share